# XSLT muenchian grouping with the help of key

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to get to a solution and so far have got nothing.
What I am trying to achieve is to transform

```
Input:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Query>
        <ID>123123</ID>
        <NameOfTeam>Team1</NameOfTeam>
        <RaisingYear>2014</RaisingYear>
        <Brief>N/A</Brief>
        <TeamMembers>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person1</Name>
            <Role>Role1</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person2</Name>
            <Role>Role2</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>N/A</Name>
            <Role>
              Role4
            </Role>
          </Member>
        </TeamMembers>
        <TeamMembers2>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person3</Name>
            <Role>Role3</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person4</Name>
            <Role>Role4</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person5</Name>
            <Role>Role5</Role>
          </Member>
        </TeamMembers2>
        <Projects>
          <Project>NISAR</Project>
        </Projects>
        <Documents>
          <Document>
            <Language>en</Language>
            <LanguageName>English</LanguageName>
            <GeneralInfo>Useless project</GeneralInfo>
            <Authors>
                <Author>Author1</Author>
                <Author>Author2</Author>
            </Authors>
          </Document>
        </Documents>
      </Query>
      <Query>
        <ID>123124</ID>
        <NameOfTeam>Team2</NameOfTeam>
        <RaisingYear>2012</RaisingYear>
        <Brief>N/A</Brief>
        <TeamMembers>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person6</Name>
            <Role>Role1</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person7</Name>
            <Role>Role2</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person8</Name>
            <Role>Role3</Role>
          </Member>
        </TeamMembers>
        <TeamMembers2>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person3</Name>
            <Role>Role3</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person4</Name>
            <Role>Role4</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person5</Name>
            <Role>Role5</Role>
          </Member>
        </TeamMembers2>
        <Projects>
          <Project>MissionMars</Project>
        </Projects>
        <Documents>
          <Document>
            <Language>en</Language>
            <LanguageName>English</LanguageName>
            <GeneralInfo> </GeneralInfo>
          </Document>
          <Document>
            <Language>en</Language>
            <LanguageName>English</LanguageName>
            <GeneralInfo>It is a rubbish comment</GeneralInfo>
          </Document>
          <Document>
            <Language>fr</Language>
            <LanguageName>English</LanguageName>
            <GeneralInfo>It is another rubbish comment.</GeneralInfo>
          </Document>
        </Documents>
    </Query>
</Root>
```

to

```
Output:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Query>
        <ID>123123</ID>
        <NameOfTeam>Team1</NameOfTeam>
        <RaisingYear>2014</RaisingYear>
        <Brief>N/A</Brief>
        <TeamMembers>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person1</Name>
            <Role>Role1</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person2</Name>
            <Role>Role2</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>N/A</Name>
            <Role>
              Role4
            </Role>
          </Member>
        </TeamMembers>
        <TeamMembers2>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person3</Name>
            <Role>Role3</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person4</Name>
            <Role>Role4</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person5</Name>
            <Role>Role5</Role>
          </Member>
        </TeamMembers2>
        <Projects>
          <Project>NISAR</Project>
        </Projects>
        <Documents>
          <Document>
            <Language>en</Language>
            <LanguageName>English</LanguageName>
            <GeneralInfo>Useless project</GeneralInfo>
          </Document>
        </Documents>
      </Query>
      <Query>
        <ID>123124</ID>
        <NameOfTeam>Team2</NameOfTeam>
        <RaisingYear>2012</RaisingYear>
        <Brief>N/A</Brief>
        <TeamMembers>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person6</Name>
            <Role>Role1</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person7</Name>
            <Role>Role2</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person8</Name>
            <Role>Role3</Role>
          </Member>
        </TeamMembers>
        <TeamMembers2>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person3</Name>
            <Role>Role3</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person4</Name>
            <Role>Role4</Role>
          </Member>
          <Member>
            <Name>Person5</Name>
            <Role>Role5</Role>
          </Member>
        </TeamMembers2>
        <Projects>
          <Project>MissionMars</Project>
        </Projects>
        <Documents>
          <Document>
            <Language>en</Language>
            <LanguageName>English</LanguageName>
            <GeneralInfo>It is a rubbish comment</GeneralInfo>
          </Document>
          <Document>
            <Language>fr</Language>
            <LanguageName>English</LanguageName>
            <GeneralInfo>It is another rubbish comment.</GeneralInfo>
          </Document>
        </Documents>
    </Query>
</Root>
```

All document with same ID and Language information should be merged and if any of the details in document tag is empty than it should be replaced, only if available, by other document tag's information with same language tag.

The code that I am using for it is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="QueryIDAndLangauge" match="Query" use="concat(ID, '+', Documents/Document/Language)"/>

  <xsl:key name="DocumentsAndLanguage" match="Language" use="Language"/>

  <xsl:key name="DocumentsAndLanguageValue" match="Language" use="concat(ID, '+', .)"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "Query[generate-id()
          =
           generate-id(key('QueryIDAndLangauge',
                          concat(ID, '+', Documents/Document/Language)
                          )
                           [1]
                      )
           ]
   "/>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Document">
    <Document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "key('DocumentsAndLanguage', ../../ID)
        [generate-id()
        =
         generate-id(key('DocumentsAndLanguageValue',
                         concat(../../ID, '+', Langauge)
                         )
                          [1]
                     )
         ]
    "/>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in Advance.

P.S.: Needless to mention, I am doing it in XSLT 1.0

Comment: Your input is not quite well-formed. You are missing a couple of opening `<member>` tags. Thanks!

Comment: Dude. I might have made some mistakes but your solution was perfect. :D I have fallen in love with your way of explanation. Thanks I owe you a treat. :)

Comment: Is there any way to add subnodes if any exists? for ex, if there is a subnode? Updating my question

Comment: If this current question has already been answered (and accepted), it is probably better you ask a whole new question if you have some new question. Thanks!

Comment: I guessed the new question is part of this question itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are combining `Document` elements with the same language within a single `Query`, then you probably only need one key here

```
<xsl:key name="Document" match="Document" use="concat(../../ID, '+', Language)"/>
```

Then you get the distinct `Document` elements like so:

```
<xsl:template match="Document[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Document', concat(../../ID, '+', Language))[1])]">
```

Then, for each child node of the `Document` you can output the children by using the key to find the first empty node

```
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$current-group/*[name() = name(current())][normalize-space()][1]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

(Where `current-group` is a variable set to the current key value).

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="Document" match="Document" use="concat(../../ID, '+', Language)"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Document[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Document', concat(../../ID, '+', Language))[1])]">
    <Document>
        <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('Document', concat(../../ID, '+', Language))" />
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select="$current-group/*[name() = name(current())][normalize-space()][1]" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Document"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```